# edit option group those belongs to only rds Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-rds

Is there any way I can segregate option group on the basis of resource they are attached to. 
I have to make changes to the rds group who are attached to RDS (oracle) not to the snapshot and I have to perform this from powershell.

Comment: What do you mean by "on the basis of resource they are attached to"? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I want to make changes to  option group who are attached to oracle database only. I also have mysql databases which I don't want to change. I also have a few option group which are attached to only snapshot. I don't want to touch them either. In other words I only want to make changes to those option group who are attached to "oracle database" and those who are attached to DB not to snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

There is no link **from** the Option Group **to** the Database.

However, there is a link **from** the Database **to** the Option Group.

It looks like you would need to:

- Call [Get-RDSDBInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-RDSDBInstance.html) on the desired database
- In the result, look at `OptionGroupMemberships`, which is a list of `OptionGroupName`
- Then, call [Edit-RDSOptionGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Edit-RDSOptionGroup.html), passing in the `OptionGroupName`, and the properties to modify